# Policy has not being called

Tags: laravel

Policy not being called ((

My Policy class:[image]

My AuthServiceProvider[image]

i have tried all variants: with guessPolicyName, and manually registered policies...

my Controller:[image]

in all cases policy is not even called and  AccessDeniedHttpException This action is unauthorized is thrown...

Any ideas?

Comment: but the code does go to the store method, is that correct?

Comment: Yes i even tried with dd() before authorize method just to be sure and it works

Comment: Does your controller extends laravel default controller?

Comment: Yes it extends from App\Http\Controllers\Controller

Comment: I'm not sure of that, but I think you can use back the auto-discovery, after that, you may run composer dump-autoload

Comment: I have already tried this way... same result(( also tried delete vendors and reinstall composer... same shit ((

Comment: Doesn't the policy method need to accept an `User` as the first argument?

Comment: As far as i know it is not necessary, User model can be authomatially injected when using HandlesAuthorization trait, any way i have tried without HandlesAuthorization trait with same result...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in authorization it self because policies doesnt works with guest users. So i decided to use middleware (in my particular case it is better than custom service provider because i have several types of guest users)

this is my middleware class[image]

i wrap my guests routes with this middleware

GuestClient is model it should extends from Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User

the policy class:
[image]
and it works))